# XPath 1.0: Select all child nodes that have a given parent, selecting empty if the parent does not have such a child node?

Tags: xpath, vtd-xml

Using XPath 1.0 and the XML below, how can I select all "c" nodes that have a "b" parent, selecting "" if a "b" parent does not have a "c" node, i.e. get `{"c1", "", "c3"}` as the resulting node-set (in document order)?

I am using VTD-XML 2.11 (Java) and I am looking for a single XPath evaluation that will return the above result without looping.

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>c1</c>
  </b>
  <b/>
  <b>
    <c>c3</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I have browsed the questions and found interesting pointers such as Oliver Becker's method, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want xpath to return a node set or a string as result?

Comment: I am looking for the xpath evaluation to return a node set comprised of the `{"c1", "", "c3"}` strings.

Comment: Is order of the nodes important?

Comment: Yes, (document) order is important.

Comment: For performance reasons, vtd-xml doesn't guarantee document order unless the course of evaluation leads naturally to it... will have to think about this to see if i can come up with some answer for u

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to evaluate these XPaths?  I can't think of a great approach, but depending on what you're using it could be easy to select all the `b`s, iterate through them, and use either the value of c or a blank value for each one.

This isn't a great approach, but it works for your sample input:

```
//b/c | //b[not(*)] | //b[not(c) and *]/text()
```

The explanation is:

- Select all `c`s under a `b`
- Select any `b` elements themselves if they have no child elements
- Select the first text node of any `b`s that have no `c` children.

This will work assuming that any `b` with child elements will have at least one text node and that the first one of those will be entirely whitespace.

Verification with XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="//b/c | //b[not(*)] | //b[not(c) and *]/text()[1]">
        <item>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output when run on your sample input:

```
<root>
  <item>c1</item>
  <item></item>
  <item>c3</item>
</root>
```

Comment: This returns `"c1", "c3", ""` when I run it, unfortunately, using VTD-XML 2.11 (Java).

Comment: I see.  I don't think that's the result that that XPath should produce (it should select the nodes in document order), but I can't think of anything better than that.  Is there a reason you don't want to use loops? Is there no way to do that with VTD-XML?

Comment: Not sure why VTD-XML does not select nodes in document order in this case, good question. Basically, I am looking to use a generic loop to evaluate multiple XPath expressions, each yielding a list of results, so can't use custom parsing logic depending on the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;

namespace Xpath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xml = @"<a>
              <b>
                <c>c1</c>
              </b>
              <b/>
              <b>
                <c>c3</c>
              </b>
              <b>x</b>
            </a>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            string xpath = "//b/c/text()|//b[count(child::*) = 0]|//b[count(child::*) = 0]/text()";

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

            XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlReader);

            XPathNavigator xpathNav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator xpathIter = xpathNav.Select(xpath);

            foreach (XPathNavigator navigator in xpathIter)
            {
                if (navigator.ValueType == typeof(string))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("'" + navigator.Value + "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
'c1'
''
'c3'
'x'
```

Comment: This returns `"c1", "c3", "", ""` when I run it (using my original XML), unfortunately, using VTD-XML 2.11 (Java).